# Evaluating the function 'function' timed out

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Environment:  Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5.2

Error:

> Evaluating the function 'function' ("Windows.Controls...ToString" in my case) timed out and needed to be aborted
>   in an unsafe way.

Answers say this commonly occurs when

> Options > Debugging > General > enable property evaluation > is
>   enabled.

I disabled this. Problem still happens. Microsoft [presents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt772252.aspx) a few options to solve this including

- Prevent the debugger from calling the getter property or ToString
  method (In my case this is 3rd party code)
- Have the target code ask the debugger to abort the evaluation (I don't know what this means.  It strikes me as "just ignore it")

Comment: ye, me too on VS 17 Community 15.5.7. Annoying. Build is really slow too. Might have to roll back to VS15...

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I found this was related to ReSharper.  Unchecking Debugger Integration from the ReSharper options solved the issue for me:

VS2017 > ReSharper > Options > Products & Features > Uncheck Debugger Integration

[image]

Comment: Thank you - this solved a lot of frustration my end (I'm on VS Enterprise 2017 15.7.4)

Comment: VS Professional 15.7.4 had this issue debugging an Excel AddIn, this solved it, thanks.

Comment: I persevered with Resharper even after it slowed my VS down to a crawl. I put up with the over-the-top nagging & hints & such. This is the last straw, I'm removing it. Begone Resharper & good riddance

Comment: This solved the issue for me on VS2019 with Resharper 2019.1.3

Answer (score 9):

This popped up for me in Visual Studio 2017. Version 15.5.2. I stopped the error with an option in the top menu:

> Debug > Options > "Use Managed Compatibility Mode"

This is not ideal. From the docs "Use Managed Compatability Mode":

> Replaces the default debugging engine with a legacy version to enable
>   these scenarios:
>
> You are using a .NET Framework language other than C#, VB, or F# that
>   provides its own Expression Evaluator (this includes C++/CLI).
>
> You want to enable Edit and Continue for C++ projects while mixed mode
>   debugging.
>
> Note that choosing Managed Compatibility mode disables some features
>   that are implemented only in the default debugging engine.

I hope to see a better fix soon. As of 2/20/2018 there is a [similar/same](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/15931/evaluating-the-function-systemreflectionassemblylo.html) open issue in the Microsoft Developer Community.

**UPDATE**

[This bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/15931/evaluating-the-function-systemreflectionassemblylo.html) is listed as closed/fixed as of 5/22/2020.

Comment: Still an issue on VS 15.7.3, and this tip still works, so thanks!

Comment: This works for me, also, this issue should be fixed in VS 15.8 Preview 4 according to comments here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/233452/evaluating-the-function-timed-out-and-needed-to-be-3.html

Comment: Saw this in VS 2019 (16.4.5). This fixed it.